# Is my furnace undersized?

Tags: hvac, insulation, central-air, basement-insulation

I have a GMVC95070CX4 furnace. Currently, it is extremely cold weather (outdoor temp. -17).  I have been experiencing poor heating and overnight .

My house is 2975 sq ft. and I have a 5 ton AC system installed.

Is my furnace undersized?

Comment: A fast search it seems a bit small, but size of house is just one factor.  Insulation of the house, where you are located(is -17 not expected or common).

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. I tried to make this a bit more readable. If I've really messed something up, please feel free to [edit] in any corrections. Also, it would be good to know what brand that model number belongs to, in case anyone wants to do some research on it.

Comment: AC size is largely irrelevant unless it is actually a heat pump. Is this a heat pump? Or is it a furnace (natural gas? propane? "electric"?) + air conditioner? Assuming it is (as is typical) a natural gas furnace, what is the rated **BTU** capacity?

Comment: Even though it's evident from the model number that the furnace is a Goodman brand gas fired 70,000 BTU, if you'll edit your question to mention that directly and perhaps re-focus the question not on "is it undersized" but rather something like "how can I diagnose whether it's under-performing" then we can probably get it re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best heat load information -- better than any heat load calculator -- is actual testing/experience in a particular building. I'll guess that in winters past this system performed satisfactorily?

You have a 70,000 BTU 95% efficient furnace and 5 ton A/C. That's pretty lop-sided toward cooling so I can guess you're probably located in the southern climates, maybe a humid area, where winter is normally relatively short and mild. You mentioned the current -17F is extreme so I'll guess this is lower than the "design temperature" your system was sized for.

In some climates, yes, your furnace would be under-sized. But with the information you've shared and the parts I've guessed, I'd believe the furnace is probably right-sized for normal/historical conditions.

That said there are some things you can do to help ensure the furnace is putting as much heat into the house as it can:

- make sure the filter is clean and not overly restrictive (the super-high MERV ratings do filter the air better, but they also limit the ability of the blower to push air through the system).
- make sure the exhaust flue and intake (if present) have good clearance from snow.
- make sure air return/intake grilles are clear - not covered by furniture or other items. If they're in the wall make sure furniture is maybe 6+ inches away.
- listen to the furnace during its heating cycles. Does it run for hours on end - both the blower *and* the burner? If it's struggling to meet the demand for heating then it should literally burn all night. If there are intermittent periods when the burner stops but the blower keeps going that's indicative of a problem with the indoor air or outdoor exhaust flow, causing the burner to be shut down (and by not burning for the full hour it would not be achieving the 70,000 BTU *per hour* capacity).
- check the house for air leaks around doors (threshold too!), windows, bathroom or kitchen vent fans, and electrical outlet and light switch penetrations in the exterior walls.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer my question, Location Wichita Kansas, After checked all those factors I found a issues on the heat exchanger and evaporator coil clogged.(Inspected by telescopy camera). Previous years the unit performance was aceptable .